# Can I match words or sentences to a pre-vectorized corpus of sentences in Python for NL processing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, vectorization

I've been searching for an answer to this specific question for a few hours and while I've learned a lot, I still haven't figured it out.

I have a dataset of ~70,000 sentences with subset of about 4,000 sentences that have been appropriately categorized, the rest are uncategorized. Currently I'm using a scikit pipeline with CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer to vectorize the data, however I'm only vectorizing based off the 4,000 sentences and then testing various models via cross-validation.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use Word2Vec or something similar to vectorize the entire corpus of data and then use these vectors with my subset of 4,000 sentences. My intention is to increase the accuracy of my model predictions by using word vectors that incorporate all of the semantic data in the corpus rather than just data from the 4,000 sentences.

The code I'm currently using is:

```
    svc = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(3, 5))),
               ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
               ('clf', LinearSVC()),
               ])

nb.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)
```

Where X_train and y_train are my features and labels, respectively. I also have a list z_all which includes all remaining uncategorized features.

Just getting pointed in the right direction (or told whether or not this is possible) would be super helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you mean, but you can definitely try to generate better word embeddings with something like Word2vec and gensim using your entire corpus of 70.000 sentences, then get sentence embeddings from these word embeddings, and then using these new embeddings to try to classify your sentences using your 4.000 sentences as training data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the answer is **yes**: you can use Word2Vec or another similar word-embedding method to get vectors of each sentence in your data, and then use these vectors both as training and testing data in a linear Support Vector Machine (SVC).

And **yes**, you can first create those vectors for your entire corpus of ~70,000 sentences before actually doing any training on your data.

---

It is however not as straightforward as the approach you're currently using.

There are many different ways to do this so I'll just go through one of them to help you get the basics of how this can be done.

Before we start and see what possible steps you can follow, let's remember that the goal here is to get one vector for each and every sentence of your corpus.

If you don't know what [word-embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) are, I highly suggest you to read about it, but in short this is just a way to link each word of a pre-defined vocabulary to a vector of a given dimension.

For instance, you would have:

```
# the vector associated with the word "cat" is the following vector of fixed-length
word_embeddings["cat"] = [0.0014, 0.6710, ..., 0.3281]
```

Now that you know this, here are the steps you *could* be following:

1. **Tokenization** - The first thing that you want to do is to [tokenize](http://tokenization%20meaning) each of your sentences. This can be done using a NLP library ([SpaCy](https://spacy.io) for instance) that will help you to:

   - split each sentence in a list of words
   - remove any punctuation from these words and converting them to lowercase
   - remove stopwords - *optionally*
   - [lemmatize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation) all the words - *optionally*
2. **Train a word embedding model** - Now that you have each sentence as a pre-processed list of words, you need to train a [word-embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) model using your corpus. There are many different algorithms to do that. I would suggest using [GenSim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) and Word2Vec or [fastText](https://fasttext.cc). What you can also do is using pre-trained word embeddings, like [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) or anything that best fits your corpus in terms of language/context. Either way, this will allow you to:

   - have one vector of pre-defined size for each and every word in your corpus' vocabulary
   - get a list of equally-sized vectors for each sentence in your corpus
3. **Adopting a weighting method** - Once you have a list of vectors for each sentence in your corpus, and mainly because your sentences vary in length (some have 6 words, some others have 13 words, etc.) what you want to do is getting **a single vector for each and every sentence**. To do this, what you can do is simply weighting the vectors corresponding to the words in each sentence. You can:

   - average all vectors
   - using weights like [TF-IDF weights](http://www.tfidf.com) to give some words more importance than others
   - use other weighting methods...
4. **Training and testing** - Finally, all you're left to do is training a model using these vectors, for instance with a linear Support Vector Machine (SVC), and testing the accuracy of your model on a test dataset (you can also use a validation dataset).

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is, if you are going to use a word2vec embedding, use one pre-trained or used generic text to generate it.

Word2vec embedding are usually used to give meaning and context to your text data, if you train an embedding using only your data, it might be biased and not represent a language. And that means it vectors doesn't carry any meaning.

After having your embedding working, you also has to think about what to do with your words, because a sentence has 1 or more words (embedding works at word level), and you want to feed your models with 1 sentence -> 1 vector. not 1 sentences -> N vectors.

People usually average or multiply those vectors so for example, for the sentence "Hello there" and an embedding of 5 dims:

Hello -> [0, 0, .2, .3, .8]
there -> [.1, .2, 0, 0, .5]

AVG Hello there -> [.05, .1, .1, .15, .65]
This is what you want to use for your models!

So instead of using TF-IDF to generate your sentence vectors, use word2vec like this and you shouldn't have any problem. I already work in a text calssification project and we ended usind a self-trained w2v embedding an ExtraTrees model with amazing results.